# Alternating Sequence Limit

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> 1. Suppose $a_{n} a_{n+1}<0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and suppose $\lim a_{n}=L$. What is $L ?$ Prove your claim.

I've encountered this weird question with limits. I feel like the answer is L=0, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I did it for you this time so you can see how it should be done.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have already provided an answer to this question. If you let us know what you have tried so far or where you are getting stuck, I can disclose it for you.

Comment: You can use contradiction. Suppose $L \neq 0$, use definition of limit with $\varepsilon = L/2$ and show that all $a_{n>N}$ should have the same sign.

Comment: @guest sure, or product rule immediately implies $L^2\le 0$ so $L=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n a_{n + 1} < 0$ for all $n$, and if we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$, then we see we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n a_{n + 1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1} = L^2 \leq 0$. Then $L = 0$.